# ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/tmp/build_3f3702f3/frontend/package.json' Heroku

Tags: heroku, deployment

App structure;[structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/INBX1.png)

I have deployed once and i get this message {"message":"ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/frontend/build/index.html'","stack":null} in the webpage. I'm struggling to figure out why this error appears and in the process I keep getting this Error in the console when I push:

```
PS C:\Users\User\MERN App> git push heroku master
Enumerating objects: 56, done.
Counting objects: 100% (56/56), done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (49/49), done.
Writing objects: 100% (49/49), 19.98 KiB | 682.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 49 (delta 33), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
remote: Updated 21 paths from 3ade352
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: -----> Building on the Heroku-22 stack
remote: -----> Using buildpack: heroku/nodejs
remote: -----> Node.js app detected
remote:        
remote: -----> Creating runtime environment
remote:
remote:        NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
remote:        NODE_VERBOSE=false
remote:        NODE_ENV=production
remote:        NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true
remote:
remote: -----> Installing binaries
remote:        engines.node (package.json):  18.5.0
remote:        engines.npm (package.json):   8.19.1
remote:
remote:        Resolving node version 18.5.0...
remote:        Downloading and installing node 18.5.0...
remote:        Bootstrapping npm 8.19.1 (replacing 8.12.1)...
remote:        npm 8.19.1 installed
remote:        
remote: -----> Restoring cache
remote:        Cached directories were not restored due to a change in version of node, npm, yarn or stack
remote:        Module installation may take longer for this build
remote:        
remote: -----> Installing dependencies
remote:        Installing node modules
remote:        
remote:        added 234 packages, and audited 235 packages in 4s
remote:
remote:        23 packages are looking for funding
remote:          run `npm fund` for details
remote:
remote:        found 0 vulnerabilities
remote:        
remote: -----> Build
remote:        Running heroku-postbuild
remote:
remote:        > mern-app@1.0.0 heroku-postbuild
remote:        > NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false npm install --prefix frontend && npm run build --prefix frontend
remote:
remote: npm ERR! code ENOENT
remote: npm ERR! syscall open
remote: npm ERR! path /tmp/build_3f3702f3/frontend/package.json
remote: npm ERR! errno -2
remote: npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/tmp/build_3f3702f3/frontend/package.json'
remote: npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
remote: npm ERR! enoent 
remote:
remote: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
remote: npm ERR!     /tmp/npmcache.IYZ6N/_logs/2023-05-27T06_58_58_335Z-debug-0.log
remote:
remote: -----> Build failed
remote:
remote:        We're sorry this build is failing! You can troubleshoot common issues here:
remote:        https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/troubleshooting-node-deploys
remote:
remote:        If you're stuck, please submit a ticket so we can help:
remote:        https://help.heroku.com/
remote:
remote:        Love,
remote:        Heroku
remote:
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app.
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote:
remote: !       Push rejected to mern-rocketchat.
remote:
To https://git.heroku.com/mern-rocketchat.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/mern-rocketchat.git'
```

package.json file.

```
  "scripts": {
"start": "node backend/server.js",
"server": "nodemon backend/server.js",
"client": "npm run start --prefix frontend",
"dev": "concurrently \"npm run server\" \"npm run frontend\"",
"heroku-postbuild": "NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false npm install --prefix frontend && npm run build --prefix frontend"}
```

backend/server.js file;

```js
const __dirname1 = path.resolve();

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
  app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname1, "/frontend/build")));

  app.get("*", (req, res) =>
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname1, "frontend", "build", "index.html"))
  );
} else {
  app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.send("API is running..");
  });
```

Why is it that `remote: npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/tmp/build_3f3702f3/frontend/package.json'` not found and why is it searching frontend in the package.json, please help.